# How to print elements of A list of Ints in one line in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, printing

I need to print a list of integers in Haskell in one line only separated by space...
Like , I would want to print

```
[6,5,4,7,3,9]
```

in this manner

```
6 5 4 7 3 9
```

I used the Map_ function but that prints all the elements in different lines.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this

```
main = putStrLn . unwords . map show $ [1,2,3,4]
```

Instead of `unwords` you could also use [`intercalate " "`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=intercalate) for a more generic function.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a customized print function, which accepts a parameter of separator:

```hs
type Separator = String
cPrint :: Show a => Separator -> a -> IO ()
cPrint sep v = putStr $ show v ++ sep

ghci> mapM_ (cPrint " ") [6,5,4,7,3,9]
6 5 4 7 3 9 ghci>
```

Comment: I don't much care for type synonyms, especially for beginners. In this case, it doesn't even seem to serve any purpose.

Comment: @dfeuer Well, it's just for readability. In my opinion, type synonym is a basic concept that every beginner should know. Anyway, just `String` is OK, and using type synonym for readability is my way of writing haskell code.

Comment: How does that make it more readable? It just introduces another layer of indirection. If not for the unfortunate existence of `String`, beginners would have no need whatsoever to learn about type synonyms.

Comment: @dfeuer For this simple example, type synonym indeed has few effects on readability. It's just a preference. At least, I can tell from the type signature directly that the first parameter passed to `cPrint` is a separator, not anything else. This is the readability. In contrast, with `String`, maybe next time when I see this code, I have to think for a while what the first parameter means.

Comment: Coming back to such code, I could see it's a separator, but wouldn't know if it was a string, a character, or text.